# SQL table for room and bed status in a hostel

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am a new student of SQL database. Today, I conceived of a system to track accommodation status in my hostel. I do not know how to plan the database field and constraints - it is giving me troubles.

What I want is:
A user can register himself to by providing his details:name, address, type of bed desired, type of room desired. The user can look for the availability of rooms and beds. For instance, Room number 1 has 2 beds (bed 1 and bed 2). Room number 2 has the same number of beds as Room number 1. I want to track Room number 1's bed status (vacated or allocated).If 1 is available, then I can register myself to Room number 1 - bed 2, by providing my details.

My analysis
Room  --  RoomID, 2 Beds, Both Beds Status
User  --  RoomID, BedID, joindate, vacatedate

Suppose Room 1-bed 2 is not allotted, I could register so that its status becomes allotted.

or some effective concept to track and register user to Room, bed-wise.

Does anyone know of an effective way to create this system?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, Each bed is allocating to users instead of allocating rooms. So BedID is the final entity.

> Js for Example: Room is like *StateInfo_Table* and Bed is the *DistrictInfo_Table*   --
>   See the table structure below:

User_table

```
UserID   int (pk)
name     varchar(50)
address  varchar(50)
```

Room_Table

```
RoomID int(PK)
RoomName
```

Bed_Table

```
BedID int(PK)
BedInfo varchar(50)
RoomID int(FK)
```

Booking_Table

```
BookingID int(PK)
BedID     int(FK)
UserID    int(FK)
CheckInTS   datetime
CheckOutTS  datetime
```

Comment: ---how i do insert operations...please help me..i m absolute beginner, track alloted an vacate room/bed info.

Comment: then step one back, you need begins really at the basics, cause u wont see the relationships and the logic why. read after it, may this can help to get clearer: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/article.php/3478051